# Buffer Test Output

Tags: go

When testing multiple packages `go test` buffers the output unless there is a failure, however when benchmarking it defaults to streaming output.

[From the 1.3 source](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/go/test.go?name=release-branch.go1.3#328) :

```
    // stream test output (no buffering) when no package has
    // been given on the command line (implicit current directory)
    // or when benchmarking.
    // Also stream if we're showing output anyway with a
    // single package under test.  In that case, streaming the
    // output produces the same result as not streaming,
    // just more immediately.
    testStreamOutput = len(pkgArgs) == 0 || testBench ||
            (len(pkgs) <= 1 && testShowPass)
```

I don't really get this behavior being forced on the user, as I don't see much use in getting the standard ouput during benchmarking.

Here is an example of my test command, which compiles a coverage profile and performs benchmarking for a single package :

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem -covermode=count -coverprofile=main.coverprofile PACKAGE
```

Am I missing something? How can I override this behavior and buffer the output even when benchmarking?

Comment: IMO this should be on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list?can=2&q=&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Release%20Owner%20Repo%20Summary)

Comment: @OneOfOne I'm new to Go, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.